# Linux Awesomewm config exclude option from menubar

Tags: linux, lua, awesome-wm

So I made my windows have rounded borders using

```
c.shape = gears.shape.rounded_rect
```

But this affects my menu bar as well (I'm using polybar) is there a way to say

```
if not menubar
```

when I tried this it made everything have sharp corners. But I only want the menubar to have sharp corners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various properties to match certain clients, such as `c.class` or `c.name` (see [here](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/core_components/client.html) for a full list of properties on a `client` object).

To find out the value to match against, run `xprop` in a terminal and click on your polybar.
It will then list various properties where `WM_NAME` maps to `c.name` and `WM_CLASS` will list `c.instance` and `c.class` in that order, separated by a comma.

For your use case, matching against `c.class` would be the recommended approach, as this translates to "match against any instance of the application polybar". It should then look similar to this:

```lua
if c.class ~= "polybar" then
    c.shape = gears.shape.rounded_rect
end
```

where you replace `polybar` with the value you got from `xprop`.